# How to parse a string which may or maynot contain newline in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, parsing

I have a text dataset like this separated by comma-

```
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS UNSORTED
VALUES ARE ( A S Q M N C H )
SEARCH IS LINEAR
,
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS NONLINEAR
,
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 02 M 0f S 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 0D N 05 P 
           17 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS LINEAR
```

sample output will be like this:
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vaID.png)

I have to parse the data to form a pandas dataframe containing columns like ***is_alphanumeric, sorted/unsorted and values***.
I have separated the file based on comma delimiter and running a for loop through each item.

```
value_name=[]
vname = re.search('VALUES ARE \( (.*) \)', line)
value_name.append(vname.group(1).replace("' '", "''"))
```

but this regex only fetches values which are in a single line. I am unable to fetch those values which are spread in multiline. One data item here shows 2 lines for values, there can be 3 as well. How do I fetch in that case. How to remove the newline character and remove the extra spaces in that case?

Comment: can you post [mre], incl sample input and output? i.e. do you read this from a file? what the expected output is? This may well be more easy to parse using string methods if we know what expected output is.

Comment: Yes, I read the input from a text file, the format I have given in the question. I have attached a sample output. Basically whatever is there with values within parentheses, I require to fetch that.

Comment: if 'comma' separates not element of line but rather paragraphs then you could parse all lines of interest to single line or list of lines to check with `re` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply flags to the regex methods that influence how matching is done - I supply ['re.DOTALL'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) so `'.'` may also match newlines and adjust the pattern for your values a bit:

- split at `','`
- extract into dictionary via regex

  - split + strip + join every dataline if `'\n'` in to remove newline and leading spaces
- set to DataFrame

---

```
text = """TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS UNSORTED
VALUES ARE ( A S Q M N C H )
SEARCH IS LINEAR
,
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS NONLINEAR
,
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 02 M 0f S 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 0D N 05 P 
          17 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS LINEAR"""
```

Code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


# map a regexpattern to the columnname in the df to store its info 
patterns = {"(IS ALPHANUMERIC)": "alphanum",
            "(IS SORTED)": "sorting",
            "(IS UNSORTED)": "sorting",
            "(IS NONLINEAR)": "search",
            "(IS LINEAR)": "search",
            "VALUES ARE \((.+?)\)": "values"}

data = []
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["alphanum", "sorting", "search", "values"])

for i,parts in enumerate(text.split(",")):
    print()
    found = {"alphanum":None, "sorting":None, "search":None, "values":None}
    for pattern, heading in patterns.items():
        match = re.search(pattern, parts, flags=re.DOTALL)
        if match:
            found[heading] = ' '.join(map(str.strip, match[1].split("\n")))
    df.loc[i] = found
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          alphanum      sorting        search                                             values
0  IS ALPHANUMERIC  IS UNSORTED     IS LINEAR                                      A S Q M N C H
1  IS ALPHANUMERIC    IS SORTED  IS NONLINEAR     0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E
2  IS ALPHANUMERIC    IS SORTED     IS LINEAR  02 M 0f S 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 0D N 05 P 17 T...
```

Answer (score 2):

@PatrickArtner provided the regex solution, just want to add solution using string methods

```
dataset = """TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS UNSORTED
VALUES ARE ( A S Q M N C H )
SEARCH IS LINEAR
,
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS NONLINEAR
,
TABLE DATA IS ALPHANUMERIC
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 02 M 0f S 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 0D N 05 P 
           17 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS LINEAR"""

def parse_chunk(chunk):
   data = {}
   headers = {'TABLE DATA IS ': 'DATA TYPE', 'TABLE IS ': 'IS_SORTED',
              'SEARCH IS ': 'SEARCH'}
   for line in chunk:
       if line.startswith('VALUES ARE ( '):
           data['VALUES'] = [line[13:-2]]
       elif line.startswith(' '):
          data['VALUES'].append(line.strip(' )'))
       else:
          for prefix, key in headers.items():
              if line.startswith(prefix):
                  data[key] = line[len(prefix):]
                  break
   data['VALUES'] = ' '.join(data['VALUES']) # combine all values chunks
   return data

      
import pandas as pd
data = [parse_chunk(chunk.splitlines()) for chunk in dataset.split('\n,\n')]
print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
[{'DATA TYPE': 'ALPHANUMERIC', 'IS_SORTED': 'UNSORTED', 'VALUES': 'A S Q M N C H', 'SEARCH': 'LINEAR'}, {'DATA TYPE': 'ALPHANUMERIC', 'IS_SORTED': 'SORTED', 'VALUES': "0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E", 'SEARCH': 'NONLINEAR'}, {'DATA TYPE': 'ALPHANUMERIC', 'IS_SORTED': 'SORTED', 'VALUES': "02 M 0f S 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 0D N 05  17 T 08 K 09 E", 'SEARCH': 'LINEAR'}]
      DATA TYPE IS_SORTED                                             VALUES     SEARCH
0  ALPHANUMERIC  UNSORTED                                      A S Q M N C H     LINEAR
1  ALPHANUMERIC    SORTED     0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E  NONLINEAR
2  ALPHANUMERIC    SORTED  02 M 0f S 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 0D N 05  17 T ...     LINEAR
```